# Efficiently sort a column of a two-dimensional array in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, quicksort

I create a 2-dimensional Array in C via malloc like this:

```
double **x;     
x = malloc(rows * sizeof(double*));
for (n = 0; n < rows; n++){
    x[n] = malloc(columns * sizeof(double));
    memset(x[n], 0, columns * sizeof(double));
}
```

I also check if malloc failed but for better readibility I posted that version. It actually works fine.

Now I have a function which is qsorting the elements row-wise:

```
double qsort_row_wise(double points[], int points_count)
```

Which I can call for a specific row(number 3 / 4th row) with 4+1 columns by:

```
my_qsort(x[3], 4);
```

This function is receiving a normal array and is also working well.

Now I want to use this function to qsort a column. That's why I am searching for something like this(which is not working):

```
my_qsort(x[][3], 4);
```

x[][3] here means a vector of all elements of the column 3.

If possible I would like to do a "vector"-like operation, not selecting everything step by step(for loop) for best performance.

Comment: Where did you found `vector` in C.

Comment: "a vector of all elements of the column 3". There is no such thing in the language or the standard library.

Comment: Thats actually part of my problem. As far as I know `vector` is a part of C++. I referred to vector as a 1-dimensional array. So I like to extract a 1-dim-Array from a multidimensional array.

Comment: Then the term `vector` should better be replaced, and the question and especially the title should be reworked.

Comment: Maybe it's only a confusion of mathematical and programming terms? I think *column*, *row* and *two-dimensional array* would be more helpful to get your problem solved.

Comment: To add another phrase "matrix": What your 1st code snippet creates isn't a matrix, nor a 2d-array, but one 1d-array of pointers, with each element pointing to a 1d-array of `double`s. Such a construct sometimes is called a "scattered" array, as it consists of "number of rows"+1 not necessarily continuous blocks of memory.

Comment: @alk: Why isn't that a matrix? The number of entries in each row is the same and the element can be accessed with `x[row][col]`. Whether the matrix is stored a contiguous 2darray or as flat 1d array with pointer into it or as shown here is an implementation detail. As fas as I know, "matrix" isn't a C term, but a term in the problem domain.

Comment: It's a matrix in the mathematical sense, yes. But it isn't by it's "physical" layout. @MOehm

Comment: I removed the confusing `vector`s from the question, hope the actual problem is still intact.

Comment: @Wolf: Thanks! You were right I have more of a mathematical background and its my first day on stackoverflow.

Comment: I wonder why this was downvoted.

Comment: @TimFinnegan *`its my first day on`* -- Welcome to SO, have a good time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want a 2D array, it is better to allocate it as a single contiguous block:

```
double *x = calloc(rows * columns, sizeof(double)); // does zero init
```

Now you can index using arithmetic, so your `my_qsort` function should be declared like this:

```
void my_qsort(double *start, size_t count, size_t stride);
```

Now to sort row 3 you can do this:

```
my_qsort(x + 3 * columns, columns, 1);
```

And to sort column 5 you can do this:

```
my_qsort(x + 5, rows, columns);
```

During the sort, the elements you need to access are `start[ii * stride]`, where `ii` goes from `0` to `count`.  And `start` of course is simply the first cell in the 2D array that you wish to sort--typically either the leftmost cell in a row or the top cell in a column.  It is also possible to use the same function to sort part of a row or column, or to sort an arbitrary "line" through the matrix, e.g. the diagonal of a square matrix:

```
my_qsort(x, rows, columns + 1);
```

Having a single allocation to store your 2D array not only makes "strided" operations easier, it is also more efficient, because it reduces the number of allocations, improves spatial locality, and on Linux, increases the chances that the memory will be instantly reclaimed when you `free` it, because "large" allocations are done via `mmap` rather than `sbrk`.

Comment: Thanks John! I didnt know this is even faster. Would you also prefer that for huge datasets (>10GB)? Even with much more dimensions?

Comment: @TimFinnegan: Generally yes.  There are special cases such as "jagged" arrays (rows have varying lengths) or subsetting/combining where the array-of-pointers approach can save space, but you'll know those cases if/when they appear.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks again! You helped me quite a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Well, you need to create an array the size of how many rows you have since a columns consists of n rows.

```
double *cols = malloc(nofrows * sizeof(double));
```

then loop through the 2 dimensional array over the rows and use the column index as a constant:

```
int whichcolumn = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
  cols[i] = x[i][whichcolumn];
```

then pass cols to the qsort function

```
qsort_row_wise(cols, nofrows);
```

Comment: It's not clear that you are only describing the extraction and sorting part, maybe it would be better to make this more explicit, and maybe also to add the integration part after the sort placeholder. Just an idea...

Answer (score 1):

> If possible I would like to do a vector-operation, not selecting everything step by step(for loop) for best performance.

This is not possible.

What your 1st code snippet creates isn't a 2D-array, but one 1D-array of pointers, with each element pointing to a 1D-array of `double`s. Such a construct sometimes is called a "scattered" array, as it consists of "number of rows"+1 not necessarily continuous blocks of memory.

Concluding from the latter fact, you cannot extract a column, as the elements are distributed throughout the memory and cannot be addressed by a single operation.

Comment: Thanks alk! That helped a lot!

Comment: @TimFinnegan: You are welcome and I surely appreciate your comment. However as you mention, you were new at SO: Here we say "Thank you!" by up-voting an answer. ;-)

Comment: Takes me 4 more reputation points to be allowed to up-vote ;) But I will come back ;)